# complex name of field of class in typescript

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript

I have a class in typescript like this -

```
export class News {
    title: string;
    snapshot: string;
    headerImage: string;
}
```

Now In my angular service i have a method which get list of news like this -

```
private searchNews(sortOrder : string, query? : string):Observable<News[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.url+'?'+this.buildParams(sortOrder,10,0,query))
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    }
```

here is the json data i am getting from server -

```
[{
  "jcr:path":"someurl",
  "title":"Hello News",
  "snapshot":"Here is a snapshot",
  "headerImage":"image.png"
},
 ...
]
```

Now i want to add a field **"path"** in my news class which maps value of field **"jcr:path"** of json data.

But i can't write class like this -

```
export class News {
    jcr:path:string;// I may write it as - path:string
    title: string;
    snapshot: string;
    headerImage: string;
}
```

So is there way i can tell typescript to extract value of **"path"** field from **"jcr:path"** properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the property name as a string:

```
class News {
    'jcr:path': string;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: that's great but can you please tell me if there is a way, i can keep my field name path only, so that will be easy to write in angular expression like {{news.path}} rather {{news['jcr:path']}}

Comment: That requires that you change the shape of the underlying javascript object. You can do this using a transform on your http request (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses)

Comment: Yeah that's what i was looking for. Thanks.